# Minimizing Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, kullback-leibler

[This paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2005/08/KL.pdf) is showing how KL divergence can be minimized by matching the expected values of the sufficient statistics.
More precisely,
For any distribution p of the exponential family with pdf:
$$ p_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1} {Z(\theta)}\exp(\theta^T \phi(x))$$
the distribution $$p_{θ∗} $$ which minimises the Kullback-Leibler divergence,
$$ KL (p||p_{θ∗})$$ over the exponential family with natural statistic $\phi$ is implicitly given by:
$$E_{p_{\theta}*(x)} [\phi(x)]  = E_{p_{(x)}} [\phi(x)]$$

I need help to show that this is true for the particular case of a [normal-gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-gamma_distribution). So I need to make the same proof that is on the paper but for the special case of Normal gamma.

Answer (score 1):

We already have that the sufficient statistics are
$$
T_1 = \ln T,\; T_2 = T,\; T_3 = TX,\; T_4=TX^2.
$$

You should select the approximating density $q(X,T)$. Then, by Theorem 1, you simply equate the true expectations with the expectations under the approximating distribution. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
E_q(\ln T) &= \psi(\alpha) - \ln(\beta)\\
E_q(T) &= \frac{\alpha}{\beta},\\
E_q(TX) &= \frac{\alpha\mu}{\beta},\\
E_q(TX^2) &= \frac{\alpha\mu^2}{\beta} + \frac{1}{\lambda}.
\end{align}
$$
Until you specify what your approximating density is, this is all I can say for this problem. The cited note is explaining *assumed density filtering* where the posterior distribution is the true distribution and the approximating density $q$ is an exponential family.

Comment: I don't totally understand what you explained but the density that I want to approximate is another normalgamma

Comment: That would be trivial. The KL divergence will obviously be minimized when the parameters are identical between the two normal-gamma distributions.

Comment: So here P and P* are normal gamma but they don't have the same parameters

Comment: @SamiHadouaj They will once you’ve minimized the KL divergence.

Comment: actually the goal is to find a new distribution p*  such that the kl div between p* and p (this is the normal gamma) is minimized. Based on that paper it is enough to solve the system where the expected value of the sufficient statistics w.r.t to p is equal to the expected value of the sufficient statistics with regard to p* and this is true in the general case for the exponential family. I need the proof of that same theorem but in the case that p is a normal gamma

Comment: @SamiHadouaj It is impossible to "find" a distribution that minimizes the KL divergence because the class of distributions is infinite. A family of distributions must be specified and that will give you a handle on the minimization step. And it can't be another normal gamma because the KL divergence is minimized when they're the same distribution, i.e., same parameters.

Comment: please look here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568283/minimizing-kullback-leiber-using-hessian